# Why I got error 403 pushing on github and how to fix it?

Tags: github

I just created new github repository ( with public access ) and recreated new personal access token instead
But trying to push my project to github  got error

```
user@hoster:/project/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited$ git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': petrogromovo@yahoo.com
Password for 'https://petrogromovo@yahoo.com@github.com':
remote: Permission to PetroGromovo/midone_adminarea.git denied to PetroGromovo.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PetroGromovo/midone_adminarea.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am sure that I have entered valid username and personal access token.
What can raise this error?

Some misconfigure on my github ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the access token configured (what scopes are selected)?

Comment: Thanks! I had to select in "Select scopes": “Repo”